# Class 'tx_solr_indexqueue_PageIndexer' not found

Tags: solr, typo3, scheduler

I set a Scheduled task for Solr to "Index Queue Worker", but it seems that it does not work.

When I try to Launching the Scheduled Task manually i get this error :

```
Class 'tx_solr_indexqueue_PageIndexer' not found
```

[image]

In which place should I find this class and make it work ?

Thanks

Comment: According to the screenshot you're using TYPO3 7.6. Which version of EXT:solr do you use? `tx_solr_indexqueue_PageIndexer` indicates, that you're using a very old version of EXT:solr which doesn't support namespaces. Did you upgrade your TYPO3 installation to TYPO3 7.6 recently? Then you might need to delete the old scheduler task and recreate it with the new classes.

Comment: Yes,  I updated typo3 to 7.6.32 recently. In the tab Reports, Apache Solr Version is Outdated, Unsupported : The minimum required version is 6.6.2, you have 4.10.4. So, i will need to upgrade EXT:solr to 6.6.2